# How to neatly get the sum of symmetric elements in a list?

Tags: list-manipulation

The task is to compute

```
symmSum[{a, b, c, d, e, f}]

(*==> {a+f, b+e, c+d} *)

symmSum[{a, b, c, d, e}]

(*==> {a+e, b+d, c} *)
```

My clumsy solution is

```
symmSum[l_List] := Block[{n = Length@l, res},
   res = Last@Last@Reap@Do[Sow[l[[i]] + l[[-i]]], {i, Ceiling[n/2]}];
   If[OddQ@n, res[[-1]] /= 2];
   res
   ];
```

I feel that this can be done without using `Length`, but how?

Comment: See my update for a `Length`-less solution.

Comment: Thank you all guys, it was fascinating!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Playing with patterns:

```
{a, b, c, d, e} //. {h_, b___, t : Except[_List]} :> {h + t, {b}} // Flatten
```

This can be written more efficiently, without the full rescanning inherent in `//.`, using recursion:

```
f1 = # /. {h_, b___, t_} :> Prepend[f1 @ {b}, h + t] &;
```

Also as a DownValues definition which is a bit more efficient still:

```
f2[{h_, b___, t_}] := Prepend[f2 @ {b}, h + t]
f2[x_] := x

f2 @ {a, b, c, d, e}
f2 @ {a, b, c, d, e, f}
```

> ```
> {a + e, b + d, c}
> {a + f, b + e, c + d}
> ```

---

Disregarding elegance, this is the fastest method I could come up with for packed arrays:

```
Module[{ln = Length@#, x},
  x  = #[[ ;; ⌈ln/2`⌉ ]];
  x += #[[ -1 ;; ⌊ln/2`⌋ + 1 ;; -1 ]];
  If[OddQ @ ln, x[[-1]] /= 2 ];
  x
] &
```

I imagine it can be bested by compile-to-C in v8, but I don't have that.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks!  I like your `iter` better.  I use that structure fairly often myself, and it always feels powerful (a little code goes a long way).

Comment: the first method is very impressive

Comment: @Szabolcs I added an improved method to my answer that I like best of all now.  I fear it may encroach upon your answer, however it *is* in essence my original method written recursively.

Answer (score 20):

This is a simple though somewhat wasteful solution:

```
symmSum[l_List] := Take[l + Reverse[l], Ceiling[Length[l]/2]]
```

It will give you the middle element twice, not once.  Is it important that you only get `c` (and not `2c`) when applying this function to `{a,b,c,d,e}`?  That's easy to do (avoiding computing elements twice is also easy), but will make the function slightly longer.  These solutions all use `Length` though.

---

Here's a pattern-based solution which avoids `Length`:

```
iter[{result___}, {s_, mid___, e_}] := iter[{result, e + s}, {mid}]
iter[{result___}, {}] := {result}
iter[{result___}, {mid_}] := {result, mid}

symmSum[l_List] := iter[{}, l]
```

You may want to modify this as

```
symmSum[l_List] := Block[{$IterationLimit = Infinity}, iter[{}, l]]
```

to make it work for arbitrarily long lists.

Answer (score 13):

What's wrong with `Length`? It's a very efficient function to callculate (since lists are vectors internally, i.e. arrays of fixed size, whose length is precisely known to the program at all times).

```
symSum = Module[{result, length = Length[#]},
        result = (# + Reverse@#) [[1 ;; Ceiling[length/2]]];
        If[OddQ[length], result[[-1]] /= 2];
        result
    ] &;

symSum@{a, b, c, d, e, f}
symSum@{a, b, c, d, e}
```

> ```
> {a + f, b + e, c + d}
> {a + e, b + d, c}
> ```

Comment: Nothing wrong, just a wish for perfection :-)

Answer (score 9):

With the conscious decision to eschew elegance for reliability, I present

```
symSum[li_List] := Module[{k2 = Ceiling[Length[li]/2]}, 
  Total[MapAt[Reverse, 
    If[Apply[Equal, Length /@ #], #, 
       MapAt[Function[l, PadLeft[l, k2]], #, {2}]] &[
     Partition[li, k2, k2, {1, 1}, {}]], {2}]]]
```

or more compactly,

```
symSum[li_List] := Module[{k2 = Ceiling[Length[li]/2]}, 
  Total[MapAt[Reverse, 
    PadLeft[Partition[li, k2, k2, {1, 1}, {}], {2, k2}], {2}]]]
```

Testing:

```
list = {a, b, c, d, e, f};

symSum[list]
{a + f, b + e, c + d}

symSum[Most@list]
{a + e, b + d, c}
```

---

Yet another variation:

```
symSum[li_List] := Module[{k = Length[li], k2},
  k2 = Ceiling[k/2]; 
  Total[MapAt[
    Composition[Reverse, If[EvenQ[k], Identity, RotateRight]], 
    Internal`Deflatten[PadRight[li, 2 k2], {2, k2}], {2}]]]
```

and we can keep on putting out variations until we're all blue in the face:

```
symSum[li_List] := Module[{k = Length[li], k2},
  k2 = Ceiling[k/2];
  PadRight[Total[
           Take[li, {#, # Quotient[k, 2], #}] & /@ {1, -1}], k2, test[[k2]]]]
```

Comment: baroque! +1 though

Comment: @acl if it ain't baroque, don't fix it! (I so rarely get to use that pun, and I'd apologize for it, if I felt any remorse whatsoever.)

Answer (score 9):

Here's an approach using a specially constructed (sparse) matrix:

```
symmSum[list_] := With[{n = Length[list]},
  Take[
     SparseArray[
        {Band[{1, 1}] -> 1, Band[{1, -1}, Automatic, {1, -1}] -> 1}, 
        {n, n}
        ].list, 
     Ceiling[n/2]
     ]
  ]
```

---

Test cases:

```
symmSum[{a, b, c, d, e, f}]

(*
==> {a + f, b + e, c + d}
*)

symmSum[{a, b, c, d, e}]

(*
==> {a + e, b + d, c}
*)
```

Answer (score 8):

**Recursive solution**

```
fr[l_] := Which[
  l == {}, Sequence[{}],
  Drop[l, 1] == {}, l,
  True, {First[l] + Last[l], Sequence @@ fr[Take[l, {2, -2}]]}
  ]
```

so

```
fr[{a, b, c, d, e}]
fr[{a, b, c, d, e, f}]
(*
{a + e, b + d, c}
{a + f, b + e, c + d}
*)
```

For longer lists, one would need to increase the recursion limit like so

```
Block[{$RecursionLimit = \[Infinity]}, 
 fr[RandomInteger[{-5, 5}, 1000]]]
(*lots of stuff*)
```

**Previous solutions**

For lists of even length,

```
(#[[1 ;; -1 ;; 2]] + Reverse@#[[2 ;; -1 ;; 2]]) &
```

does what you want. For odd lengths, I don't see how to avoid `Length`.

**length without `Length`**

```
length[lst_] :=
 Module[{i},
  i = 1;
  NestWhile[(i += 1; Rest@#) &, lst, Rest[#] \[NotEqual] {u} &];
  i
  ]
```

a bit silly though.

**Locating the centre of a list**

Here is how to find the central position of an odd-length list (returns `$Failed` for even-length lists):

```
findMiddle[lst_] := If[
    # == {},
    $Failed,
    First@First@#] &@Position[
   Function[
     {l},
     MapThread[
      Equal,
      {l, Reverse@l}
      ]
     ]@MapIndexed[First@#2 &, lst],
   True
   ]
```

(please note this is not serious, so do not point out inefficiencies!).

Comment: ...asuming the odd list doesn't have any symmetrical elements other than the middle one. The one for even lists doesn't work, try it for a list of more than 4 elements

Comment: @rojo oops true! the first seems to work..

Comment: I run the first with {a, b, c, d, e, f} as input and get {a+f, c+d, b+e} instead of {a+f, b+e, c+d}

Comment: @Rojo I see, I had not interpreted the question this way (ie that the order is important)

Answer (score 6):

What about

```
sumSym = Block[{$RecursionLimit = Infinity},
    Flatten[
       If[Length[#1] <= 
           1, #1, {Total[#1[[{1, -1}]]], #0[#1[[2 ;; -2]]]}] &[#]] &[#]
    ] &;
```

or cuter but slower, avoiding nesting 3 functions and the flatten

```
Block[{$RecursionLimit = Infinity}, 
  If[Length[#1] <= 1, #1, {Total[#1[[{1, -1}]]], 
    Sequence @@ #0[#1[[2 ;; -2]]]}]] &
```

An incredibly slow solution that uses Length (hehe, what am I posting this for) could be

```
ReplaceList[r, {{i___, b_, ___, e_, j___} /; 
    Length[{i}] == Length[{j}] :> b + e,
  {i___, m_, j___} /; Length[{i}] == Length[{j}] :> m}]
```

Answer (score 6):

Yet another possible solution:

```
sumSym[x_List]:= 
  Module[{len=Length[x]~Quotient~2,
          extra=Length[x]~Mod~2==1,
          result},
    result = x[[Range[len]]] + x[[-Range[len]]];
    If[extra,Append[result,x[[len+1]]],result]]
```

Example:

```
sumSym@{a,b,c,d,e,f}   
(*
==> {a + f, b + e, c + d}
*)

sumSym@{a,b,c,d,e}
(*
==> {a + e, b + d, c}
*)
```

Comment: Better to write `extra = OddQ[Length[x]]`, no?

Comment: I just recently learned that the `*Q` functions are *not* the right choice if you want to check mathematical properties (see http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/601/129).

Comment: That's for symbolic evaluation. Here, you can almost always expect `Length[x]` to return *some* integer that `OddQ[]` certainly won't choke on...

Answer (score 5):

Using `ListConvolve`:

```
ClearAll[partsF, lcF]
partsF = Module[{fl = Floor[Length[#]/2], cl = Ceiling[Length[#]/2]}, {#[[1 + fl ;;]], 
     PadRight[#[[;; fl]], cl]}] &;
lcF = First@ListConvolve[## & @@ partsF@#, {-1, 1}, {}, Plus, List] &;
```

Examples:

```
lcF[{a, b, c, d, e, f}]
```

> {a + f, b + e, c + d}

```
lcF[{a, b, c, d, e}]
```

> {a + e, b + d, c}

Without using `Length`:

```
ClearAll[lcF2]
lcF2 = First@ListConvolve[#, #, {-1, 1}, {}, Plus, 
     Composition[Last /@ # /. Times -> (#2 &) &, Gather, List]] &;

lcF2[{a, b, c, d, e, f}]
```

> {a + f, b + e, c + d}

```
lcF2[{a, b, c, d, e}]
```

> {a + e, b + d, c}

Answer (score 4):

**Using `TakeList`:**

```
Clear["Global`*"];

edgeSum[k_List] := Module[{n = Length@k},
   alt = Array[(-1)^(# + 1) &, n];
  Sequence @@@ TakeList[k, alt] //
    Partition[#, UpTo[2]] & //
   Map[Total]
  ]

edgeSum /@ {{a}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, c, d}, {a, b, c, d, e}, {a,
    b, c, d, e, f}}
```

---

**Addendum**

After studying @kglr's recent answer:

```
h = Total@
    MapThread[#1[#2] &, {
      {Identity, Reverse}
      , PadLeft@
       TakeList[#, {Ceiling@(Length@#/2), -Floor@(Length@#/2)}]
      }
     ] &;
h /@ {{a}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, c, d}, {a, b, c, d, e}, {a, b, c,
    d, e, f}}
```

---

*Result*

> {{a}, {a + b}, {a + c, b}, {a + d, b + c}, {a + e, b + d, c}, {a + f,
> b + e, c + d}}

Answer (score 3):

```
foo[dt_] :=
   With[{le = Length @ dt}, 
     Plus @@@ 
       Map[dt[[#]]&, 
         Append[If[OddQ @ le, {-Ceiling[le/2]}, Nothing]] @
           Thread[{#, -#}] &[Range[le/2]]]]

foo /@ {{a}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, c, d}, {a, b, c, d, e}, {a, b, c, d, e, f}}
```

{{a}, {a + b}, {a + c, b}, {a + d, b + c}, {a + e, b + d, c}, {a + f,
b + e, c + d}}

Answer (score 3):

```
symTotal = Total@PadRight@{#, Reverse@#2}&@@TakeDrop[#, Ceiling[Length[#]/2]]&;
```

***Examples:***

```
symTotal @ {a, b, c, d, e}
```

> ```
> {a + e, b + d, c}
> ```

```
symTotal @ {a, b, c, d, e, f}
```

> ```
> {a + f, b + e, c + d}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Taking advantage of the fact that [`Flatten`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html) [may be used](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126/106) to transpose a 'ragged' array:

```
symPartition[lst_List]:=Flatten[#,{{2}}]&@MapAt[Reverse,-1]@Partition[lst,
    UpTo[Ceiling[Length@lst/2]]]

symPartition/@{{a},{a,b},{a,b,c,d},{a,b,c,d,e}}

(* {
    {{a}},
    {{a,b}},
    {{a,d},{b,c}},
    {{a,e},{b,d},{c}}
   } *)
```

To get the sum:

```
MapApply[Plus]@*symPartition/@{{a},{a,b},{a,b,c,d},{a,b,c,d,e}}

(* {
    {a},
    {a+b},
    {a+d,b+c},
    {a+e,b+d,c}
   } *)
```

Just for fun:

```
TableForm[MapApply[Plus]@*symPartition/@(Alphabet[][[#]]&/@Range@Range[26])]
```

\begin{array}{ccccccccccccc}
 \text{a} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} &
   \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 \text{a}+\text{b} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} &
   \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 \text{a}+\text{c} & \text{b} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} &
   \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 \text{a}+\text{d} & \text{b}+\text{c} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} &
   \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 \text{a}+\text{e} & \text{b}+\text{d} & \text{c} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} &
   \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 \text{a}+\text{f} & \text{b}+\text{e} & \text{c}+\text{d} & \text{} & \text{} &
   \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 \text{a}+\text{g} & \text{b}+\text{f} & \text{c}+\text{e} & \text{d} & \text{} &
   \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 \text{a}+\text{h} & \text{b}+\text{g} & \text{c}+\text{f} & \text{d}+\text{e} &
   \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} &
   \text{} \\
 \text{a}+\text{i} & \text{b}+\text{h} & \text{c}+\text{g} & \text{d}+\text{f} &
   \text{e} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} &
   \text{} \\
 \text{a}+\text{j} & \text{b}+\text{i} & \text{c}+\text{h} & \text{d}+\text{g} &
   \text{e}+\text{f} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} &
   \text{} & \text{} \\
 \text{a}+\text{k} & \text{b}+\text{j} & \text{c}+\text{i} & \text{d}+\text{h} &
   \text{e}+\text{g} & \text{f} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} &
   \text{} & \text{} \\
 \text{a}+\text{l} & \text{b}+\text{k} & \text{c}+\text{j} & \text{d}+\text{i} &
   \text{e}+\text{h} & \text{f}+\text{g} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} &
   \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 \text{a}+\text{m} & \text{b}+\text{l} & \text{c}+\text{k} & \text{d}+\text{j} &
   \text{e}+\text{i} & \text{f}+\text{h} & \text{g} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} &
   \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 \text{a}+\text{n} & \text{b}+\text{m} & \text{c}+\text{l} & \text{d}+\text{k} &
   \text{e}+\text{j} & \text{f}+\text{i} & \text{g}+\text{h} & \text{} & \text{} &
   \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 \text{a}+\text{o} & \text{b}+\text{n} & \text{c}+\text{m} & \text{d}+\text{l} &
   \text{e}+\text{k} & \text{f}+\text{j} & \text{g}+\text{i} & \text{h} & \text{} &
   \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 \text{a}+\text{p} & \text{b}+\text{o} & \text{c}+\text{n} & \text{d}+\text{m} &
   \text{e}+\text{l} & \text{f}+\text{k} & \text{g}+\text{j} & \text{h}+\text{i} &
   \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 \text{a}+\text{q} & \text{b}+\text{p} & \text{c}+\text{o} & \text{d}+\text{n} &
   \text{e}+\text{m} & \text{f}+\text{l} & \text{g}+\text{k} & \text{h}+\text{j} &
   \text{i} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 \text{a}+\text{r} & \text{b}+\text{q} & \text{c}+\text{p} & \text{d}+\text{o} &
   \text{e}+\text{n} & \text{f}+\text{m} & \text{g}+\text{l} & \text{h}+\text{k} &
   \text{i}+\text{j} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 \text{a}+\text{s} & \text{b}+\text{r} & \text{c}+\text{q} & \text{d}+\text{p} &
   \text{e}+\text{o} & \text{f}+\text{n} & \text{g}+\text{m} & \text{h}+\text{l} &
   \text{i}+\text{k} & \text{j} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 \text{a}+\text{t} & \text{b}+\text{s} & \text{c}+\text{r} & \text{d}+\text{q} &
   \text{e}+\text{p} & \text{f}+\text{o} & \text{g}+\text{n} & \text{h}+\text{m} &
   \text{i}+\text{l} & \text{j}+\text{k} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 \text{a}+\text{u} & \text{b}+\text{t} & \text{c}+\text{s} & \text{d}+\text{r} &
   \text{e}+\text{q} & \text{f}+\text{p} & \text{g}+\text{o} & \text{h}+\text{n} &
   \text{i}+\text{m} & \text{j}+\text{l} & \text{k} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 \text{a}+\text{v} & \text{b}+\text{u} & \text{c}+\text{t} & \text{d}+\text{s} &
   \text{e}+\text{r} & \text{f}+\text{q} & \text{g}+\text{p} & \text{h}+\text{o} &
   \text{i}+\text{n} & \text{j}+\text{m} & \text{k}+\text{l} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 \text{a}+\text{w} & \text{b}+\text{v} & \text{c}+\text{u} & \text{d}+\text{t} &
   \text{e}+\text{s} & \text{f}+\text{r} & \text{g}+\text{q} & \text{h}+\text{p} &
   \text{i}+\text{o} & \text{j}+\text{n} & \text{k}+\text{m} & \text{l} & \text{} \\
 \text{a}+\text{x} & \text{b}+\text{w} & \text{c}+\text{v} & \text{d}+\text{u} &
   \text{e}+\text{t} & \text{f}+\text{s} & \text{g}+\text{r} & \text{h}+\text{q} &
   \text{i}+\text{p} & \text{j}+\text{o} & \text{k}+\text{n} & \text{l}+\text{m} &
   \text{} \\
 \text{a}+\text{y} & \text{b}+\text{x} & \text{c}+\text{w} & \text{d}+\text{v} &
   \text{e}+\text{u} & \text{f}+\text{t} & \text{g}+\text{s} & \text{h}+\text{r} &
   \text{i}+\text{q} & \text{j}+\text{p} & \text{k}+\text{o} & \text{l}+\text{n} &
   \text{m} \\
 \text{a}+\text{z} & \text{b}+\text{y} & \text{c}+\text{x} & \text{d}+\text{w} &
   \text{e}+\text{v} & \text{f}+\text{u} & \text{g}+\text{t} & \text{h}+\text{s} &
   \text{i}+\text{r} & \text{j}+\text{q} & \text{k}+\text{p} & \text{l}+\text{o} &
   \text{m}+\text{n} \\
\end{array}

Answer (score 1):

Using `Table` and `Gather`:

```
F[list_] := Module[{l, pl, dpl, pt},
    l = Length @ list;
    pl = Function[
            Gather[
                Table[(Part[#, i] + Part[#, -i]) / 2,
                        {i, Length @ #}
                    ]
            ]
        ][list];
    dpl = Map[Greater[#, 2] &, Map[Length, pl]];
    pt = Catenate[Map[Partition[#, 2, 1] &, pl]];
    Which[
            Or[
                And[SameQ[DuplicateFreeQ[list], True],
                    SameQ[FreeQ[dpl, True], True]
                ],
                And[SameQ[DuplicateFreeQ[list], False],
                    SameQ[FreeQ[dpl, True], True]
                ]
            ],
                Map[Total, pl],
            And[SameQ[DuplicateFreeQ[list], False],
                SameQ[FreeQ[dpl, True], False]
            ],
                MapApply[Sequence,
                    {Map[Total, Most @ pt], Function[Total[# / 2]][Last @ pt]}
                ]
        ]
   ];
```

Test:

```
l1 = {a};
l2 = {a, b};
l3 = {a, b, c};
l4 = {a, b, c, d};
l5 = {a, b, c, d, e};
l6 = {a, b, c, d, e, f};
l7 = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g};
l8 = {a, b, c, c, b, a};
l9 = {a, 0, 0, 0, 0};(*An example suggested by Syed*)
l10 = {a, b, b, b, b};

F /@ {l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, l6, l7, l8, l9, l10} // Column
```

[image]

Comment: Please call the second function with a different name. It is easier to check without getting `Tag is Protected...` errors. Use `{a, b, c, c, b, a}` as a test case. The result should be `{2a, 2b, 2c}`.

Comment: Thanks mate! With the new function, I already obtain the correct results :-)

Comment: Please use `{a, 0, 0, 0, 0}` as a test case.

Comment: It's not as pretty anymore, but it works :-)