# Why does Assuming[x > 0, TrueQ[x > 0]] return False?

Tags: symbolic, expression-test

```
Assuming[x>0,TrueQ[x>0]]
```

should, as I understand it, test `TrueQ[x>0]` **after** assuming `x>0`. Could someone explain the output `False` to me, please?

Comment: Related discussion: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/601/why-does-mathematica-claim-there-is-no-even-prime

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because the assumption system is not called during the standard evaluation sequence, it is only called when `Simplify`, `FullSimplify`, `Sum`, `Integrate` etc... are used.
Thus, `x>0` remains unevaluated:

```
Assuming[x > 0, x > 0] 
(*
==> x > 0
*)
```

and `TrueQ` then returns `False`:

```
Assuming[x > 0, TrueQ[x > 0]]
(*
==> False
*)
```

If, however, you run `Simplify` before `TrueQ`, you get the expected result

```
Assuming[x > 0, TrueQ[Simplify[x > 0]]]    
(*
==> True
*)
```

---

As an aside, there is some "hidden" functionality in the `` Assumptions` `` context that lets you perform various checks and calculations within the assumption system. Run `` ?Assumptions`* `` to see what's available. You code, in particular, could be written as

```
Assuming[x > 0, Assumptions`APositive[x - 0]]
(*
==> True
*)
```

Comment: I should probably emphasis that [TrueQ](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TrueQ.html) is a syntactic test that "yields `True` if its argument is `True`, and yields `False` otherwise."

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the Assumptions context.