# IntegerQ returning False despite setting Assumptions

Tags: function-construction, assumptions

Why does the following not return True?

```
Assuming[z ∈ Integers, IntegerQ[z]]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

I tried this on a fresh session of *Mathematica* 10.0.2.0.

I understand that `IntegerQ` does return False if it cannot determine whether the argument is an integer, but in the above case it should be possible to this.
I have a vague idea that this questions is similar to [this one posted already](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3541/26656), however the workaround of using `Simplify` proposed there does not work in my case.

In case you want to have more details about my actual problem, I'm trying to define a function taking integer arguments. I want to define separate branches of the function, depending on whether the argument is even or odd. Now, using `EvenQ` and `OddQ` as a constraint on the function definition runs into the same problem that I describe above.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: [This post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1835/7167) is useful, if not closely related.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically `IntegerQ` is for determining whether the object inside it *is* an integer, not whether it *represents* an integer.  Since `z` is a `Symbol`, we get `False`.

As for your function, I'm assuming you're using some variant of `If[EvenQ[z], ___]`.  As you said, this won't work because `EvenQ` will always return `False` on a symbol since `z` does not have head `Integer`.

Try this instead:

```
f[n_ ? OddQ] := Row[{n, " is odd"}]
f[n_ ? EvenQ] := Row[{n, " is even"}]
```

If your argument is not an integer, the function will be held unevaluated until it gets explicitly replaced by an integer.

Comment: Thanks! You were exactly right with your guess of what I was trying to achieve. Thanks very much for telling me the proper way of how to define such functions!

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation (`ref/IntegerQ`):

`IntegerQ[expr]` returns `False` unless `expr` is manifestly an integer (i.e. *has head* `Integer`). [emph added]

Evidently the assumption does not make `z` an actual integer, that is, an expression whose head is `Integer`.

Comment: Thanks, I now understand the result of the little test.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe obvious but if you want to test if $z$ represents an integer you can use:

```
Assuming[z \[Element] Integers, Simplify[z \[Element] Integers]]
```

This gives

```
True
```