# Constructing a symbolic Hermitian matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, physics

I need to construct a symbolic Hermitian matrix like

```
m = {
     {           n, a, b, b},
     {Conjugate[a], n, b, b},
     ...
    }
```

but I am not able to set the variables `n, a, b` in order to obtain a Hermitian matrix. I tried with `$Assumptions` but after that `HermitianMatrixQ[m]` gives me `False` as a result. I need that for a Cholesky decomposition of the `m` matrix.

Comment: You might be surprised to find that `CholeskyDecomposition[{{a, b, c}, {b, d, e}, {c, e, f}}]` works as expected...

Comment: The root cause of this problem is the issue described in [this answer by @Leonid](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/607/245) - that's at least the conclusion I drew in my answer below.

Answer (score 14):

By default, Mathematica assumes symbols to be complex. However the elements on the main diagonal of a Hermitian matrix are necessarily real. To force Mathematica to interpret the elements on diagonal of `m` to be real you could replace them by their real part, i.e.

```
m = {{Re[n], a, b, b}, {Conjugate[a], Re[n], b, b}, 
     {Conjugate[b], Conjugate[b], Re[c], d}, 
     {Conjugate[b], Conjugate[b], Conjugate[d], Re[e]}};

HermitianMatrixQ[m]

(* output: True *)

CholeskyDecomposition[m]
```

Answer (score 12):

A reasonable alternative, is to construct an explicitly Hermitian matrix by exploiting the fact that any matrix, $M$, can be written as the sum of a Hermitian matrix, $H$, and a [skew-Hermitian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-Hermitian_matrix) (or anti-Hermitian, if your in physics) matrix, $S$. This implies that a matrix can be made Hermitian simply by

$$H = \frac{1}{2}(M + M^\dagger)$$

or skew-Hermitian via

$$S = \frac{1}{2}(M - M^\dagger),$$

from which it is plainly obvious that $M = H + S$.

This is implemented in Mathematica via

```
SquareMatrixQ[m_?MatrixQ] := Equal@@Dimensions[m]
SquareMatrixQ[_] := False

makeHermitian[m_?SquareMatrixQ] := (m + ConjugateTranspose[m])/2
makeSkewHermitian[m_?SquareMatrixQ] := (m - ConjugateTranspose[m])/2
```

where I included the test `SquareMatrixQ` as Mathematica does not have a built-in equivalent.

They give the following results

```
m = {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}}

makeHermitian[m] // FullSimplify
(*{{Re[a], 1/2 (b + Conjugate[d]), 1/2 (c + Conjugate[g])}, 
   {1/2 (d + Conjugate[b]), Re[e], 1/2 (f + Conjugate[h])}, 
   {1/2 (g + Conjugate[c]), 1/2 (h + Conjugate[f]), Re[i]}
  }
*)
```

and

```
makeSkewHermitian[m] // FullSimplify
(*{{a - Re[a], 1/2 (b - Conjugate[d]), 1/2 (c - Conjugate[g])}, 
   {1/2 (d - Conjugate[b]), e - Re[e], 1/2 (f - Conjugate[h])}, 
   {1/2 (g - Conjugate[c]), 1/2 (h - Conjugate[f]), i - Re[i]}
  }
*)
```

Without `FullSimplify` the the diagonals are left in the form `j + Conjugate[j]` or `j - Conjugate[j]`, respectively. It is interesting to note that the diagonals of the skew-Hermitian matrix should be purely imaginary (and are), but `FullSimplify` reduces it to `j - Re[j]` instead of `Im[j]`.

Comment: The non-uniqueness of this representation could be a problem (depending on the application). As an example, consider `(makeHermitian[m] == makeHermitian[m + I (# + Transpose[#]) &[RandomInteger[10, {3, 3}]]]) // FullSimplify`

Answer (score 7):

A Hermitian matrix of dimension $N$ has $N^2$ real parameters. However, in the answer by rcollyer I see a larger number of parameters in the form of complex numbers (which means the representation isn't unique). In Heike's solution (which is from the [documentation for `HermitianMatrixQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HermitianMatrixQ.html)) we have to write `Re[n]` on the diagonal which is OK in principle but creates the impression as if `n` as a complex number has significance, which of course it doesn't.

So one should be able to specify the real-valuedness of the diagonal elements as an assumption instead. That's what I'm testing below:

```
Clear[h];
mat =
  Table[If[i <= j, h[i, j], Conjugate[h[j, i]]], {i, 3}, {j, 3}];
MatrixForm[mat]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  h(1,1) & h(1,2) & h(1,3) \\
>  h(1,2)^* & h(2,2) & h(2,3) \\
>  h(1,3)^* & h(2,3)^* & h(3,3) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

The documentation states that `HermitianMatrixQ[mat]` is "effectively" equivalent to `ConjugateTranspose[mat] == mat`. Let's see if that is true:

```
Assuming[{Apply[And, Map[# ∈ Reals &, Diagonal[mat]]]}, 
 Simplify[ConjugateTranspose[mat] == mat]]

(* ==> True *)

Assuming[{Apply[And, 
   Map[# ∈ Reals &, Diagonal[mat]]]}, 
 Simplify[HermitianMatrixQ[mat]]]

(* ==> False *)
```

It is not the same. So it may be that the problems of the OP have to do with this inconsistency. My suggestion therefore would be to **avoid** using `HermitianMatrixQ` as a test, and use the first variant instead.

**Edit**

Since `HermitianMatrixQ` appears to be used internally, we're stuck with it and need to follow Heike's answer, or the one I give below.

The key word in the documentation is that the matrix passed to `HermitianMatrixQ` must be **explicitly** hermitian. This means that although it does evaluate its arguments, it doesn't evaluate properly with `$Assumptions` when attempting to `Simplify`. That appears to severely limit the extent to which one can do symbolic matrix manipulations. I just checked that the same behavior also happens for `SymmetricMatrixQ`.

**Edit 2: a new solution without `Re[...]`**

This seems to be the general policy for *all* conditionals that end in `...Q`: the test is performed syntactically without using assumptions.

To get a neat representation of a hermitian matrix that is *manifestly* hermitian, one could use the following definition:

```
dimension = 3;
Clear[h];
diagonal = Table[Unique["h"], {dimension}];
Map[(# /: Conjugate[#] = #) &, diagonal];
mat = Table[
   If[i <= j, h[i, j], Conjugate[h[j, i]]], {i, dimension}, {j, 
    dimension}];
mat = mat - DiagonalMatrix[Diagonal[mat]] + DiagonalMatrix[diagonal];
MatrixForm[mat]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{h3} & h(1,2) & h(1,3) \\
>  h(1,2)^* & \text{h4} & h(2,3) \\
>  h(1,3)^* & h(2,3)^* & \text{h5} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
HermitianMatrixQ[mat]
```

> `True`

Here I did *not* have to forcibly use real parts `Re` on the diagonals. Instead, I used `TagSet` to define the complex conjugate of each diagonal element to be equal to itself. That is sufficient to convince Mathematica that it is a real number.

Comment: @Jeans, in fact if I try a decomposition the answer is the following  CholeskyDecomposition::herm: The matrix {{h[1,1],h[1,2],h[1,3]},{Conjugate[h[1,2]],h[2,2],h[2,3]},{Conjugate[h[1,3]],Conjugate[h[2,3]],h[3,3]}} is not Hermitian or real and symmetric. >>. It is not necessary to test if the matrix is symmetric but I need to use this decomposition and it works only if Mathematica feels one hermitian matrix (also positive)

Comment: I'm having trouble coming up with an example of the non-uniqueness of my decomposition. Could you show me, please?