# How to find solutions that yield of root of unity?

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic, polynomials

I have a polynomial with coefficients that are integer polynomials in another (complex) variable. For example:

```
1 + (1 - v^2) #1 + (-3 - v^2) #1^2 + #1^3 &
```

I want to solve for $v$ such that the second root of this polynomial is a root of unity. Notice that $v=0$ is such a solution:

```
In[67]:= Root[1 + (1 - v^2) #1 + (-3 - v^2) #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2] /. {v -> 0}
Out[67]= 1
```

My two attempts to pull this information out of Mathematica have not worked. Namely,

```
In[68]:= Reduce[RootOfUnityQ[Root[1 + (1 - v^2) #1 + (-3 - v^2) #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2]], {v}]
Out[68]= False
```

and

```
In[66]:= Solve[RootOfUnityQ[Root[1 + (1 - v^2) #1 + (-3 - v^2) #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2]], {v}]
Out[66]= {}
```

both say that there are no solutions, which is not the answer that I am looking for.

## Question:

How do I solve for $v$ such that some expression is a root of unity?

Comment: Have you noticed that this function is *linear* in $v^2$? This means that a very simple formula for $v$ can be found as the square root of a rational function of `#1`. Replacing `#1` by $\exp(2 k \pi i/n)$ for integral $k$ and nonzero integral $n$ finishes the job.

Answer (score 4):

`Reduce[1 + (1 - v^2) (x + I y) + (-3 - v^2) (x + I y)^2 + (x + I y)^3 == 0 && x^2 + y^2 == 1, {y, x, v}]` seems to give what you want. In general, one might wish to try expanding complex variables into explicit real and imaginary parts, if the usual treatments do not work.

Comment: Note that the condition `x^2 + y^2 == 1` does not necessarily guarantee that `x + I y` is a root of unity, but this is at least a starting point...

Comment: Along those lines, I suppose that `Reduce[1 + (1 - v^2) x + (-3 - v^2) x^2 + x^3 == 0 && 
  Exists[n, Element[n, Integers] && n > 0 && x^n == 1], {x, v}]` would work, but I have no idea how long it will take to execute given that there is an existential quantifier.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why your attempts didn't work is that `RootOfUnityQ` like all functions ending in Q gives `False` if the object cannot be determined right away as unit root. For example `RootOfUnityQ[x]` evaluates straight to `False`, and so does `RootOfUnityQ[Root[1 + (1 - v^2) #1 + (-3 - v^2) #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2]]`. So e.g. your first attempt basically reduces to `Reduce[False, {v}]` which of course evaluates to `False`.

It is easy to be fooled by those `*Q` functions which from their name look more like mathematical functions than structural ones, see e.g. the answers on [Why does Mathematica claim there is no even prime?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/601/why-does-mathematica-claim-there-is-no-even-prime) for more detailed explanations of those `*Q` functions. I consider them one of the most confusing functionalities (if not *the* most confusing functionality) of Mathematica, but basically, the key thing to remember is that all `*Q` functions have an implied `TrueQ`.

As of a mathematical expression which could replace `RootOfUnityQ` I think in many cases `Abs[x] == 1`, while not exactly equivalent, should suffice. For those where it doesn't, maybe `Log[x]/(I Pi) \[Element] Rationals` would be a good replacement.